# Vectorizing a for loop in R that uses the unique function

Tags: r, list, loops, unique, vectorization

```
player_ids = c(34, 87, 27, 34, 87, 9, 29, 25, 24, 25, 34, 37)
end = length(player_ids)
unique_players_list = list()

for(i in 1:end) {
  unique_players_list[[i]] = unique(player_ids_unlisted[1:i])
}
```

This is (a shortened version of) the for loop I am trying to vectorize. I'm not sure how to post code output, however the list unique_players_list should having the following output:

```
unique_players_list[[1]] == c(34)
unique_players_list[[2]] == c(34)
unique_players_list[[3]] == c(34, 87)
unique_players_list[[4]] == c(34, 87, 27)     
unique_players_list[[5]] == c(34, 87, 27)
```

"and so on. the output does not have to be in a list, and I would actually prefer a dataframe, however i need this vectorized because my current for loop takes forever and I need to run this code tens of thousands of times."

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really vectorization - it's accumulation. You could probably do this very efficiently with a single `unique` call and `match` to get the position of the first occurrence of each of the elements.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would want this in a data frame as the result seems non-rectangular by definition. Are you hoping for a column of vectors?

Comment: I know what the max number of unique elements in the entire container is, and would create that many columns for the dataframe

Comment: yes sorry, I did mean `= unique(player_ids[1:i])`

Comment: I don't think it's very fast, but this is essentially `Reduce(union, player_ids, accumulate=TRUE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fairly literal implementation of the question is to lapply along the player ids, returning the unique elements of the head of the ids

```
f0 <- function(player_ids)
    lapply(seq_along(player_ids), function(i) unique(head(player_ids, i)))
```

This avoids the need to manage the allocation of the result list, and also handles the case when `length(player_ids) == 0L`. For a more efficient implementation, create the list of 'cummulative' sets

```
uid <- unique(player_ids)
sets <- lapply(seq_along(uid), function(i) uid[seq_len(i)])
```

then identify the set belonging to the ith index

```
did <- !duplicated(player_ids)
sets[cumsum(did)]
```

Here are some of the solutions so far

```
f1 <- function(player_ids) {
    end = length(player_ids)
    tank <- player_ids[1]

    unique_players_list = vector("list", end)
    for(i in 1:end) {
        if (!player_ids[i] %in% tank) tank <- c(tank, player_ids[i])
        unique_players_list[[i]] = tank
    }
    unique_players_list
}

f2 <- function(player_ids) {
    un = unique(player_ids)
    ma = match(un, player_ids)
    li = vector("list", length(player_ids))

    for (i in seq_along(player_ids))
        li[[i]] = un[ma <= i]
    li
}

f3 <- function(player_ids) {
    uid <- unique(player_ids)
    sets <- lapply(seq_along(uid), function(i) uid[seq_len(i)])
    sets[cumsum(!duplicated(player_ids))]
}
```

Some basic tests that they are generating reasonable results

```
> identical(f1(player_ids), f2(player_ids))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f1(player_ids), f3(player_ids))
[1] TRUE
```

and an assessment of performance for a larger data set

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> ids <- sample(100, 10000, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(f1(ids), f2(ids), f3(ids), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
    expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
 f1(ids) 24397.193 25820.375 32055.5720 26475.8245 28030.866 56487.781    10
 f2(ids) 20607.564 22148.888 34462.5850 24432.4785 51722.208 53473.468    10
 f3(ids)   414.649   458.271   772.3738   501.5185   686.383  2163.261    10
```

`f3()` does well when the vector of initial values is large compared to the number of unique values. Here's a data set where the elements in the original vector are mostly unique, and the timings more comparable

```
> ids <- sample(1000000, 10000, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(f1(ids), f2(ids), f3(ids), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1(ids) 214.2505 232.3902 233.7632 233.4617 237.5509 249.4652    10
 f2(ids) 433.5181 443.5987 512.4475 463.8388 467.3710 949.4882    10
 f3(ids) 299.2291 301.4931 307.7576 302.9375 316.6055 321.3942    10
```

It can be important to get the edge cases correct, a common problem being a zero-length vector, e.g., `f2(integer())`. `f1()` does not handle this case. Interestingly, I think all implementations are agnostic to the type of input, e.g., `f1(sample(letters, 100, TRUE))` works.

Some off-line discussion lead to the suggestion that the return format is neither convenient nor memory efficient, and that `duplicated()` and `unique()` are somehow similar operations so we should be able to get away with a single call. This lead to the following solution, which returns a list of the unique identifiers and the offsets, for each player_id, to the end of the unique identifiers

```
f5 <- function(player_ids) {
    did <- !duplicated(player_ids)
    list(uid = player_ids[did], end_idx = cumsum(did))
}
```

The results are not directly comparable with `identical()` or similar. An updated `f3()` is

```
f3a <- function(player_ids) {
    did <- !duplicated(player_ids)
    uid <- player_ids[did]
    sets <- lapply(seq_along(uid), function(i) uid[seq_len(i)])
    sets[cumsum(did)]
}
```

Here are a couple of metrics of performance

```
> ids <- sample(100, 10000, TRUE)
> print(object.size(f3(ids)), units="auto")
4.2 Mb
> print(object.size(f5(ids)), units="auto")
39.8 Kb
> microbenchmark(f3(ids), f3a(ids), f5(ids), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
    expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 f3(ids) 437.663 445.091 450.3965 447.3755 452.629 476.016    10
f3a(ids) 342.378 351.408 385.0844 354.2375 369.861 638.084    10
 f5(ids) 125.956 127.684 129.9898 128.5890 130.202 140.521    10
```

and

```
> ids <- sample(1000000, 10000, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(f3(ids), f3a(ids), f5(ids), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
     expr        min         lq         mean     median          uq         max
  f3(ids) 816317.361 821892.902  911862.5561 831274.596 1107496.984 1112586.295
 f3a(ids) 824593.618 827590.130 1009032.9519 829197.863  838559.619 2607916.641
  f5(ids)    213.677    270.397     313.1614    282.213     315.683     601.724
 neval
    10
    10
    10
```

Comment: Beautiful! I'm amazed how much faster your `f3` is.

Comment: This solution is ingenious

Comment: When I run your second benchmark, I still see f3 winning by a wide margin (relative times around 10:7:4 for f1:f2:f3) on R 3.2.5.

Comment: @Frank when I ran (bumped up to `times = 50`) my relative results were `2.2 : 1.6 : 1`,  which are very close to yours (and a different order than those posted in the answer).

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there is a typo in your posted code. I think you mean

```
unique_players_list[[i]] = unique(player_ids[1:i])
```

Well, the reason why your loop is slow, is that you perform `unique()` in each iteration. In i-th iteration, the costs is `O(i)`, then as you loop along `1:n`, the costs aggregate to `O(n^2)`, which is eventually too costly.

What we want is a linear cost: `O(n)`. The following code does this. Basically we initialize `tank` to hold identified unique values, then update it as new values comes up.

```
player_ids <- c(34, 87, 27, 34, 87, 9, 29, 25, 24, 25, 34, 37)
end <- length(player_ids)
tank <- player_ids[1]

unique_players_list <- vector(mode = "list", end)
for(i in 1:end) {
  if (!player_ids[i] %in% tank) tank <- c(tank, player_ids[i])
  unique_players_list[[i]] <- tank
}
```

For operation of such type, with dependency of (i+1)-th result on i-th result, vectorization is impossible.

Comment: pre-allocate the `unique_players_list` to avoid repeated copying, `unique_players_list = vector("list", end)`

Comment: yep, try with `player_ids = sample(100, 10000, TRUE)`; for me pre-allocation is 10x faster.

Comment: this is all running much faster for me, thanks Zheyuan Li. However, unique players list is now blank for almost all of the elements, only when a new unique element is found is the if case entered and the list updated -- although this is a fix I can do on my own

Comment: @ZheyuanLi that sounds like a new question, probably too long for comments and it would be interesting for it to be searchable and have a well-written answer. (nice answer, btw)

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit how much trial and error was involved - I knew something could be done with `unique` and `match` (since `match` matches the first occurrence), and then I just tried two or three things until it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it like this. We can use lots of vectorized functions before the loop and just use simple indexing inside the loop.

```
un = unique(player_ids)
ma = match(un, player_ids)
li = vector("list", length(player_ids))

for (i in seq_along(player_ids)) {
    li[[i]] = un[ma <= i]
}

head(li)
# [[1]]
# [1] 34
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 34 87
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 34 87 27
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 34 87 27
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 34 87 27
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 34 87 27  9
```